# How to call different function for different wx.TreeCtrl Items in wxpython?

Tags: tree, wxpython, function-call

How to call different function for different wx.TreeCtrl item. when I call Fun_ASTER in second tree item, it returns last value from USGS item(first item in the tree).

```
    root = self.tree.AddRoot('Spectral Database')
    files = []
    self.dname = []
    self.test = []

    self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'USGS')
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.\USGS'):
            for filename in filenames:
                files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                self.test.append(filename)
                self.tree.AppendItem(self.tree.GetLastChild(root), filename)
            self.dname = files[:]                
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.Fun_USGS, self.tree)

    self.tree.AppendItem(root,'ASTER')
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.\ASTER'):
            for filename in filenames:
                files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                self.tree.AppendItem(self.tree.GetLastChild(root), filename)
            self.dname = files[:]
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.Fun_ASTER, self.tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a coded example that people can run, rather than cutting and pasting partial pieces of code, more people will answer your question.
Few people want to guess at missing code fragments.

Make it easy to answer your question.

You are binding a single event to 2 functions, so whichever function you bound the event to last, will be the function that is run.
You may want to make that function, look at the selected item and make a decision about what to do with it or one of the details of the event object itself may decide for you.

Either way, here is some code to help you on your way.

```
import wx
import os

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(660,300)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(600,300),
             style=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE, validator=wx.DefaultValidator)
        root = self.tree.AddRoot('Spectral Database')
        files = []
        self.dname = []
        self.test = []

        self.tree.AppendItem(root, 'USGS')
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./image'):
                for filename in filenames:
                    files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                    self.test.append(filename)
                    self.tree.AppendItem(self.tree.GetLastChild(root), filename)
                self.dname = files[:]

        self.tree.AppendItem(root,'ASTER')
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./image2'):
                for filename in filenames:
                    files.append(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                    self.tree.AppendItem(self.tree.GetLastChild(root), filename)
                self.dname = files[:]

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.Fun_Selected, self.tree)

        self.Show()

    def Fun_Selected(self, event):
        self.item = event.GetItem()
        if self.item:
            print("Selected: %s\n" % self.tree.GetItemText(self.item))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None,title="The Main Frame")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I traced the problem, actually I forgot to append filename in self.test[] from ASTER/image2 folder. thanks.

Comment: Using the list `self.test` to store the filename, you are doubling your work load, as that information is stored in the `tree` object, as you can see, from my example. That said, if your way works, run with it.

Comment: As an extra note to illustrate the importance creating a good question, had you posted the code of the function `Fun_ASTER` this would have seen by quite a few people instantly. A tip for the future. As it is you found your own error, the best type of learning experience. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you @Rolf of Saxony. I tried to embed code for the same but it raises error of indentation.

Comment: Come on! You can code a tree control but complain about an indentation error. Really! :(